# Retry mechanism for producer's client of ActiveMQ with JMS and spring

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Is there a mechanism or example implementation of a retry mechanism/solution for a producer using ActiveMQ with JMS (more precisely, with JmsTemplate) and spring framework ?
My use case, which I want to handle is, when the broker is not available, for example, I want to make some number of retries, maximum 6 (if possible with exponential delays between each). So, I need also to track the number of retries for a message between each attempt.
I am aware the the redelivery policy for the consumer, but also I want to implement a reliable producer's client side as well

Thanks, 
Simeon

Comment: This document might help you on same . http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html

Comment: Thanks, failover transport reference is a good example for a topology solution, which definitely gives a good add-on to achieve a readability, but I would like also to protect messages to be not lost and ensure they will be delivered to the broker, also in the cases when there are no any broker available. The idea is, when I have such a case, to persist all messages in the db and when the broker's connection comes back to send all persisted messages. I would like to catch unavailability of any broker in the consumer it-self via retry mechanism

Comment: Actually, failover transport with combination with the TransportListener gives  a nice solution, as well. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think that the easiest way is to use what exists for this by using an embedded broker with persistence enabled which must be used by the producer to send the messages to and by creating a Camel route to read from local Queue and forward to the remote one or by using a `JmsBridgeConnector` or `NetworkConnector` nut i think the `JmsBridgeConnector` is easier.
here is an Spring code example  :
producer have to use `jmsConnectionFactory()` to create a `ConnectionFactory`

```
package com.example.amq;

import java.io.File;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.apache.activemq.network.jms.JmsConnector;
import org.apache.activemq.network.jms.OutboundQueueBridge;
import org.apache.activemq.network.jms.ReconnectionPolicy;
import org.apache.activemq.network.jms.SimpleJmsQueueConnector;
import org.apache.activemq.store.PersistenceAdapter;
import org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBPersistenceAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ActiveMQConfiguration {
    public static final String DESTINATION_NAME = "localQ";

    @Bean // (initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
        final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.addConnector("vm://localhost");
        SimpleJmsQueueConnector simpleJmsQueueConnector = new SimpleJmsQueueConnector();
        OutboundQueueBridge bridge = new OutboundQueueBridge();
        bridge.setLocalQueueName(DESTINATION_NAME);
        bridge.setOutboundQueueName("remoteQ");
        OutboundQueueBridge[] outboundQueueBridges = new OutboundQueueBridge[] { bridge };
        simpleJmsQueueConnector.getReconnectionPolicy().setMaxSendRetries(ReconnectionPolicy.INFINITE);
        simpleJmsQueueConnector.setOutboundQueueBridges(outboundQueueBridges);
        simpleJmsQueueConnector.setLocalQueueConnectionFactory((QueueConnectionFactory) jmsConnectionFactory());
        simpleJmsQueueConnector.setOutboundQueueConnectionFactory(outboundQueueConnectionFactory());
        JmsConnector[] jmsConnectors = new JmsConnector[] { simpleJmsQueueConnector };
        broker.setJmsBridgeConnectors(jmsConnectors);
        PersistenceAdapter persistenceAdapter = new KahaDBPersistenceAdapter();
        File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "kaha");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        persistenceAdapter.setDirectory(dir);
        broker.setPersistenceAdapter(persistenceAdapter);
        broker.setPersistent(true);
        broker.setUseShutdownHook(false);
        broker.setUseJmx(true);
        return broker;
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueConnectionFactory outboundQueueConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                "auto://localhost:5671");
        connectionFactory.setUserName("admin");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("admin");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
        connectionFactory.setObjectMessageSerializationDefered(true);
        connectionFactory.setCopyMessageOnSend(false);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

**By using Camel :**

```
import org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent;
import org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQConfiguration;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class ActiveMQCamelBridge {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addComponent("inboundQueue", ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("tcp://localhost:61616"));
        ActiveMQComponent answer = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("tcp://localhost:5671");
        if (answer.getConfiguration() instanceof ActiveMQConfiguration) {
            ((ActiveMQConfiguration) answer.getConfiguration()).setUserName("admin");
            ((ActiveMQConfiguration) answer.getConfiguration()).setPassword("admin");
        }
        context.addComponent("outboundQueue", answer);
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("inboundQueue:queue:localQ").to("outboundQueue:queue:remoteQ");
            }
        });
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(60 * 5 * 1000);
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From what I see the idea is to have a local broker, where all messages are being persisted in a file and then being forwarded via the JmsBridgeConnector to the remote broker. Writing all messages to the file, does not reflect to the performance too much ? And also, if the remote broker is down, am I currently understanding that all messages being sent to the local broker during the downtime, will stay there (in the local broker) until the remote one is up again and all messages to be forwarded ?

Comment: if the remote broker is down, am I currently understanding that all messages being sent to the local broker during the downtime, will stay there (in the local broker) until the remote one is up again and all messages to be forwarded ==> yep

Comment: Writing all messages to the file, does not reflect to the performance too much ?  ==> messages are persisted in KahaDBStore

Comment: i have updated 
  simpleJmsQueueConnector.getReconnectionPolicy().setMaxSendRetries(ReconnectionPolicy.INFINITE);

Answer (score 0):

Producer does not provide any kind of retry mechanism like consumer. You need to make sure in your code that message sent by producer acknowledge by broker.

Comment: thanks for the comment, do you have an example solution or idea of a retry mechanism with producer ?